# Oracle Apex: After IG refresh or update row is not selected

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

Problem:

My editable IG is not selecting after refresh/update. scenario is as follows:

I have to refresh the IG based on select drop-down so for each value of the drop-down there will be different data needs to be shown in IG for that I have to refresh.
Need to add and delete rows from IG from other multi-select box basically after selection I am fetching data from database and refreshing IG to update it. 
So while doing above operations the selected row data is lost and its giving me error on IGSetitem.js that row is not selected.

[Error-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l59dI.png)

[Error-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJpPS.png)

Tried solutions:

I tried several solutions mentioned in the APEX community for IG but nothing seems to ´be working below I found on github IG cheat-sheet. By the way my APEX version is 19.2.

Set Selected Rows After Refresh
https://community.oracle.com/thread/4060416
and also applied some solutions from other sources.
On page load set up a handler for when the page changes (this fires after the refresh and other times as well).

Example:

```
On page load set up a handler for when the page changes (this fires after the refresh and other times as well).
```

```
window.gSel = null;

apex.region("emp").widget().on("gridpagechange", function(e, ui) {

    if (gSel) {

        apex.region("emp").widget().interactiveGrid("setSelectedRecords", gSel);

        gSel = null;

    }

});
```

Then to refresh and save selection do this:

```
var r = apex.region("emp");

gSel = r.widget().interactiveGrid("getSelectedRecords");

r.refresh();
```

Can anyone help me on this sooner would be better.

Comment: Would it be possible to set-up a small example to demonstrate your issue at apex.oracle.com?

Comment: I agree with Hari_639. Putting an example on apex.oracle.com would be helpful. If you'd rather meet briefly online, please DM me on Twitter (https://twitter.com/dmcghan) or contact me via my blog (https://jsao.io/contact/)